# Importance of synonym instead of granting an access to object

Tags: plsql

Suppose I have employee table in my department schema and I want to give permission to sales department for selecting a data from it. what is the importance of synonym in this case as I could do it by granting a permission to particular set of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `department.employees` is your table.

And you have granted select permission to `sales` user by executing the following statement from the department schema.

```
grant select on employees to sales;
```

This statement just gave the select permission to the user/schema `sales`.

But when the user `sales` try to execute the following statement,

```
select * from employees;
```

he will get the following error,

```
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Because, `employees` tables is not present in `sales` schema. It is in `department` schema.

If the user `sales` try to execute the following statement instead,

```
select * from department.employees;
```

he will get the results.

But, prefixing the `department` schema name in every query that refers to `employees` table is an overhead and most of the developers would not appreciate doing it. That's where synonyms comes to help.

`department` user creates a synonym for `department.employees` by the following statement

```
create public synonym employees for department.employees
```

Then `sales` user would be able to run the select query on `employees` table without prefixing the schema name `department`

Notes:

1. Here I have created a `public` synonym. If you omit the `public` from the synonym creation statement, synonym would be private to the schema. But then, the synonym and the table name cannot be same.
2. There are some privileges required to create different kinds of synonyms. To learn more about it, please go through [Orale Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7001.htm#CJAJCDDF)

Comment: Thanks for giving me simplified explanation